# Check my work: $\lim a_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim \sqrt{a_n} = 0 $? (for $a_n$ positive)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, continuity

I'm trying to prove, as "properly" as possible the following:$$\left[ \lim z_n = z \right] \iff \left[ \lim x_n = x \quad \wedge \quad \lim y_n = y \right]$$

where $z_n = x_n + i y_n$ and $z=x+iy$.

For the converse direction, I have $\lim |x_n - x|=0$ and $\lim |y_n - y|=0$, then I show this implies $\lim |x_n - x|^2=0$ and $\lim |y_n - y|^2=0$ so that $$\lim |x_n - x|^2 +|y_n - y|^2 =0 $$

Now I want to say this implies $\lim \sqrt{|x_n - x|^2 +|y_n - y|^2 }=0 = \lim |z_n-z|$ because of the fact that $f:x \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=0$. But is this justified, given that $f$ is undefined to the left of $0$? Does that matter at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $0\leq a<\varepsilon^2$, then $0\leq\sqrt{a}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, that's much simpler than my method. But is the argument with continuity of the square root wrong? For a function to be continuous at a point, it needs to be defined in its neighbourhood right? Or can I just say it's "right side" continuous or something?

Comment: @DepeHb: Yes, it's right continuous, and that suffices here.  But how do you know it's right continuous?  It basically comes down to the statement above.  More generally, for a function $f$ defined only on a subset of $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, $f$ can be defined to be continuous at $a\in A$ if for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in A$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, it follows that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.  (Notice the requirement $x\in A$.)  In particular, the square root function with domain $[0,\infty)$ is continuous at each point under this definition.